# What's the difference between Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores and Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a confused about three packages in asp.net core identity. I don't know what's the difference between each other. And also which of those should we use?

I found this link in GitHub, but I didn't get it.

[Difference between Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1646)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core

This assembly contains the entity definition of the entire asp.net core Identity framework, roughly including `IdentityUser`,`IdentityRole` ,`IdentityUserRole`, `IdentityUserClaim`, `IdentityRoleClaim`, `IdentityUserLogin`.It can also be understood as a database table.

- Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores

This assembly is mainly used to perform basic CRUD to the above entities, including user management (`UserManager`) and role management (`RoleManager`), and some configurations that can be performed, such as user name restrictions, password verification, and so on. Specific storage implementations need to download other packages, such as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` which is the implementation of data storage using EF Core.

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

This assembly is used to manage authentication and authorization in the AspNetCore project, and also includes the basic configuration in the AspNetCore project. For example, to use the Identity framework, you need to execute `services.AddIdentity <TUser> ()` in the `ConfigureServices` method.

Basic secondary development is based on the above core packages. If you want asp.net core Identity to support other ORM frameworks, such as Dapper, then you can use `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores` for secondary development. Or if some business
logic does not meet your special needs, and it is also developed using this package.

If you want to extend the field, you need the `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` package, and inherit the relevant classes.

Comment: I just downloaded the Identity.Core package and it seems different from what you tell here. So I would consider update this answer as .NET Core Identity 3.1 seems to have changed a bit.